# How to use 3D array's Sum function?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 3d array `double[][][] arr`, which it's actually an array of `double[][] matrix`, I want to Sum all the matrices inside the array, I was going to write a Sum function, but I saw this function which I don't know how to use it in multidimensional array and I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

```
double[][][] m;
m.Sum<double>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it can't be `Sum<double>` because `double[][][]` implements `IEnumerable<double[][]>`. So you can have two solutions here, using the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) LINQ method:

1) Write a method `double[][] AddMatrices(double[][] m1, double[][] m2)` and then use:

```
 var result = arr.Aggregate(AddMatrices);
```

2) Create a class `Matrix` (or just download one of many existing solutions), which has `Add` method, or overloaded `operator+` and then similarly:

```
 var result = arr.Aggregate(Matrix.Add);
```

The latter is of course advised, since it's explicit and thus more readable.

And to answer your question directly: no `Sum` doesn't have multidimensional equivalent out-of-box, as you can see looking at [its overload list in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Vote for `Matrix` class approach

Comment: I will go for the first option, but i only have `double [][][] arr` do you mean to use it this way `AddMatrices(arr[i], arr[i+1])` ?

Comment: @MurHaf No, when you'll have this function defined you can literally use the code I've presented: just `arr.Aggregate(AddMatrices)`. It accepts a function and uses it adequately.

Answer (score 0):

```
double[][][] m = new double[2][][];
m[0] = new double[2][];
m[1] = new double[2][];
m[0][0] = new double[2];
m[0][1] = new double[2];
m[1][0] = new double[2];
m[1][1] = new double[2];
m[0][0][0] = 0;
m[0][0][1] = 1;
m[0][1][0] = 2;
m[0][1][1] = 3;
m[1][0][0] = 4;
m[1][0][1] = 5;
m[1][1][0] = 6;
m[1][1][1] = 7;
var summ = m.SelectMany(f => f.SelectMany(g => g)).Sum(); // summ = 28.0

double[, ,] n = new double[2, 2, 2];
n[0, 0, 0] = 0;
n[0, 0, 1] = 1;
n[0, 1, 0] = 2;
n[0, 1, 1] = 3;
n[1, 0, 0] = 4;
n[1, 0, 1] = 5;
n[1, 1, 0] = 6;
n[1, 1, 1] = 7;
var sumn = n.Cast<double>().Sum(); // sumn = 28.0
```

Comment: Sum 2x2 matrix with 2x2 matrix will give 2x2 matrix, not a single number